# Set Theory: Semi-convex sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Struggling with a Discrete Math homework problem:

Allow semi-convex sets to be defined by set $S$, a subset of the real line such that whenever $a$ and $b$ are in $S$, their average $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is also in S.

1. Which of these sets are semi-convex: $\emptyset$, $\{2\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{0,1,2\}$, $\{x\ |\ 0<x<2\}$, $\{x\ |\ 0<=x<=2\}$, the rational numbers, the whole real line.
2. What cardinal numbers are possible for the size of a semi-convex set? Explain.
3. Prove or disprove: If $S$ and $T$ are semi-convex, then $S \cup T$ is semi-convex.
4. Prove or disprove: If $S$ and $T$ are semi-convex, then $S \cap T$ is semi-convex.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a semiconvex set is called *midconvex*.

1. Let $a\ne b$. Then $\{a,b\}$ is not semiconvex, because the midpoint $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is not in this set. Try to use this example.
2. The set ot all rationals is semi-convex. A finte set is semiconvex iff it is a singleton. Any convex set is semiconvex, so any cardinality of a convex set is good.
3. What about two singletons?
4. Trivial by definition.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Two questions: 1. Would an empty set be semiconvex? 2. What do you mean by trivial by definition?

Comment: A convex infinite set of reals covers an interval so it has the cardinal of the reals. But an infinite semi-convex  set of reals can have any infinite cardinality not exceeding that of the reals. How many such cardinals ? See "Continuum Hypothesis."

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q 3.

Let $S_1\subset \mathbb R.$ For $n\in \mathbb N$ let $S_{n+1}= \{(a+b)/2:a,b\in S_n\}.$ Let $T=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}S_n.$

(1). $T$ is semi-convex.

(2). If $S_1$ is semi-convex then $T=S_1.$

(3). If $S_1$ is countable and has more than one member then $T$ is countably infinite.

(4). Is $S_1$ is uncountable then the cardinal of $T$ equals the cardinal of $S_1.$  So any infinite cardinal not exceeding the cardinal of the reals is the cardinal of a semi-convex set. Whether there are any such cardinals other than $|\mathbb N|$ and $|\mathbb R|$ is undecidable from the axiom system (ZFC) of set theory.